# PHPStorm отображает методы интерфейса и не отображает методы класса

Tags: php, phpstorm

Набираю следующий код в PhpStorm

```
class MTest1 implements IPublic {
/**
* My super method
* @return static MTest1
*/
   public static function create() {
      if (<Any_Condtion>) {
        return new MTest1;
      } else {
        return null;
      }
   }
   public function action1() {
   //Здесь какие-то действия
   }
 }
```

Далее пишу следующий код

```
$m=MTest1::create();
if (!$m instanceof IPublic) {
  return;
};
$m->action1();
```

При попытке вывести подсказку по Ctrl+Shift+I в PhpStorm получаю сообщение, что метод не определен в интерфейсе IPublic.

Как мне научить PhpStorm смотреть в данном случае не только в интерфейс, но и в соответствющий класс?

Comment: Ctrl+Shift+Insert это вставка из буфера, не?

Comment: Вы правы - извнияюсь. Имел ввиду Ctrl + Shift + I . Поправил текст.